# FindRoot Domain restriction

Tags: equation-solving

I am solving a system of four non-linear equations in four variables using FindRoot. I have some sense of the relationship between the variables so I don't want Mathematica to do its computations in certain funky regions of the domain. 
For example, I want to solve:

$\begin{align}
g_1(w,x,y,z) &=0\\ 
g_2(w,x,y,z) &=0\\
g_3(w,x,y,z) &=0\\
g_4(w,x,y,z) &=0\\
\end{align}$

such that

$\begin{align}
x &\in& \{25,75\} \\ y &\in& \{0,80-f_1(x)\} \\  z &\in& \{x+f_2(x),800\} \\    w &\in& \{y,z\} \end{align}$

and I would like my FindRoot to operate only in the above domain. How can I get it to do that?

Simply writing this doesn't seem to work:

```
FindRoot[{g1==0,..,..},{x,50,25,75},{y,a,0,80-f1(x)},{z,b,x+f2(x),800},{w,c,y,z}]
```

Comment: `FindRoot[]` has no explicit support for restrictions like that, I'm afraid. What do your $g_k(w,x,y,z)$ and $f_k(x)$ look like? Maybe something could be tailored to your problem...

Comment: Can you redefine your functions such that, for instance, they take some improbable (or complex) value outside the ranges you are interested in ?

Comment: oh that sucks. My $g_k$ are very very large expressions involving $w,x,y,z$ raised to the powers of $k_i$ where $k_i$ are roots of a quartic equation and derivatives of such terms. They're huge and messy. Some of my domain restrictions, $f_i$ are linear and others I guess bound by linear relations.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Lets use `FindMinimum`**

Another way to attack this problem is to transform this as a constrained nonlinear optimization problem. Given the equations
$$
f_1(x_1,..,x_n)=0,\cdots,f_k(x_1,..,x_n)=0\\
$$
and constraints 
$$c_1(x_1,..,x_n)\bowtie0,\cdots,c_m(x_1,..,x_n)\bowtie0\\
$$
where $\bowtie \in \{<,>,\leq,\geq\}$. We form the following objective function 
$$\Gamma(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}{f_i^2(x_1,\cdots,x_n)} $$
Now it is simple to feed this problem to MMA superfunction `FindMinimum`. We use the examples of *kguler*

```
{g1, g2, g3} = {x y - z^3 + x, x y z - 2, x^2 + y^2 + z^3 - 5};
subdomain = -1 < x < 1 && -3 < y < x - x^3 && y < z < x;
res = FindMinimum[{Total[{g1, g2, g3}^2], subdomain}, {x, y, z},AccuracyGoal -> 11]
```

> {5.08374*10^-26, {x -> 0.832027, y -> -2.32619, z -> -1.03335}}

This are indeed very good solutions as the residuals for the equations $g_1=0,\cdots,g_3=0$ are seen in the following to be practically close to zero.

```
{g1, g2, g3} /. res[[2]]
```

> {1.92957*10^-13, 1.02585*10^-13, -5.50671*10^-14}

The constraints are fulfilled too

```
Boole[subdomain] /. res[[2]]
```

> 1

**How good is `FindRoot`**

On the other other hand if we use `FindRoot` the solution is not enough robust. It's convergence depends solely on the random choice of the initial guess. You can see the residual error for each equations for a run of $300$ times here. Black dots are the places where each of the three equations are satisfied with residual norm ($<10^{-8}$).

```
diffList = Transpose@{{0, 0, 0}};
neweqns = 1 - Boole[subdomain] + Boole[subdomain] {g1, g2, g3};
Monitor[For[i = 1, i <= 300, i++,
diff = (Transpose@{{g1, g2, g3}}) /. 
Quiet@FindRoot[neweqns, 
  Transpose[{{x, y, z}, {RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-3, 2}],
      RandomReal[{-2, 0}]}}]];
val = MapThread[Join[#1, #2] &, {diffList, diff}];
diffList = val;
], 
Quiet@ListLinePlot[diffList, Mesh -> All,
MeshStyle-> Directive[PointSize[.007], Red]]]
```

[image]
[image]

For a run of $300$ times we got a favorable solution using `FindRoot` $66$ times. For this example nonlinear system with a run of $10000$ the probability of finding a solution using `FindRoot` turned out to be a unimpressive $18.22\%$. So when it comes to **robustness** above constrained optimization trick using `FindMinimum` may not be a bad option.

Comment: PlatoManiac!!!! Thank you! I had thought about going the route of Lagrange multipliers and Kuhn-Tucker but I feared that I would be over complicating things but your fabulous and comprehensive post has changed my mind. I had not thought about the robustness issue at all. hmm...I think I'll try both FindRoot and FindMinimum for starters to compare what I get. Btw is it possible to accept two answers for a question here? Yours and Kgulers?

Comment: Yes, very interesting! I'm actually enrolled in a nonlinear optimization course this fall so it's nice to see an example. Where did your `AccuracyGoal` come from and why was the value of 11 selected? Does this type of optimization have a specific name I could reference or do you have a link I could look over? Thanks!

Comment: @john I guess when we call `FindMinimum` without any explicit `Method` option it chooses some kind of a Newton solver in the background. In this case as we have a symbolic objective so MMA probably takes the advantage of easily constructing a closed form Jacobian and if needed the Hessian for its internal iterative method. Given that I used the `AccuracyGoal` option to force the algorithm a precision of 11 digits. This helps often the algorithm to converge to the real optimum which is zero. Yo can check more on this option here (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AccuracyGoal.html).

Comment: Don't you think this approach is limited to small numbers of variables (like 3 or 4)?

Comment: Can't say for sure :) `FindMinimum` can handle big problems too. Propose a bigger problem and let's explore if better methods exist and how far this method can bring us with respect to big problems.

Answer (score 22):

Using a simple example with three equations in three unknowns,

```
{g1, g2, g3} = {x y - z^3 + x, x y z - 2, x^2 + y^2 + z^3 - 5};
subdomain = -1 < x < 1 && -3 < y < x - x^3 && y < z < x;
```

one can  modify the functions in the equations so that the modified functions coincide with the original functions when the constraints are satisfied. One of many possible ways doing this is to use `Boole` (or some other `Piecewise` function) as follows:

```
neweqns = 1 - Boole[subdomain] + Boole[subdomain] {g1, g2, g3};
```

Without the domain restrictions,

```
FindRoot[{g1, g2, g3}, 
 Transpose[{{x, y, z},{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-3, 2}], RandomReal[{-2, 0}]}}]]
```

possibly after several trials perturbing the initial points, gives one of the four roots:

```
(* {x->-0.5950097551413702`,y->2.6060720302882157`,z->-1.2897914523282767`} *)
subdomain /. %
(* False *)
```

The roots of `neweqns` are the roots of `{g1, g2, g3}` that also satisfy the constraints in `subdomain`. Again after possibly several trials with different initial points,

```
FindRoot[neweqns, 
  Transpose[{{x, y, z}, {RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-3, 2}], RandomReal[{-2, 0}]}}]]
```

gives

```
(* {x -> 0.832027, y -> -2.32619, z -> -1.03335} *)
subdomain /. %
(* True *)
```

**Update:** If you *have to* use `FindRoot`, it is better to re-initialize automatically when a message is issued. For example:

```
 init = {RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-3, 2}],RandomReal[{-2, 0}]}; 
 While[err == Quiet@Check[sol = FindRoot[neweqns, Transpose[{{x, y, z}, init}]], err],
      init = {RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-3, 2}], RandomReal[{-2, 0}]};]; 
 sol
```

As always, there are alternative approaches like reformulating the problem as constrained optimization and using `FindMinimum` as suggested by PlatoManiac.

`NSolve` is another alternative that allows use of constraints directly:

```
NSolve[{g1, g2, g3} == {0, 0, 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
(* {{x -> 0.832027, y -> -2.32619, z -> -1.03335},
    {x -> 1.98191, y -> -1.25951, z -> -0.801208}, 
    {x -> -3.01335, y -> 0.409805,  z -> -1.61958},
    {x -> -0.59501, y -> 2.60607, z -> -1.28979}} *)
subdomain /. %
(* {True, False, False, False} *)

NSolve[subdomain && {g1, g2, g3} == {0, 0, 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
(* {{x -> 0.832027, y -> -2.32619, z -> -1.03335}} *)
```

Comment: damn! that's so cool! Thanks you so much! I'll comment again after I implement it.